# How Move Image in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, image, move, kineticjs

How can I move an image from left to right repeatedly in KineticJS?

Also, how do I change the speed of the animation cycle?

Comment: I think this canvas tutorial does exactly what you're asking: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animate-position-tutorial/ Speed would be controlled by the period variable in this example I think.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Kinetic.Image, you could use yourImage.move(yourNewXCoordinate, yourNewYCoordinate).
For the speed, I recommend you to use TweenMax from greensock. Here's the link http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/